# Probability of visiting a city before another

Tags: probability

A businesswoman in Philadelphia is preparing an itinerary for a visit to six major cities. The distance traveled, and hence the cost of the trip, will depend on the order in which she plans her route.

a) How many different itineraries (and trip costs) are possible?

b) If the businesswoman randomly selects one of the possible itineraries and Denver and San Francisco are two of the cities that she plans to visit, what is the probability that she will visit Denver before San Francisco?

I think I understand that the number of itineraries is simply 6! because there are six cities and each time we select one we have to take that into account.

But for the second part, I am not sure what to do, does it start with findingthe probability of visiting Denver and San Francisco?

Any help or hint is well appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Of all the possible ways in which she can travel,in half of them she visits Denver before San Francisco and in half of them she visits San Francisco before Denver. Do the answer should be 6!/2

Comment: Could you tell me how you knew that in half of them she visits Denver before?

Comment: Suppose u have a sequence of number starting from 1 to 5 .now you start to arrange them however u like... Let's look at numbers 1 and 2 in all the cases either 1 will come first or 2 will come first doesn't matter the position. That's why in half cases 1 comes before 2 and in other half 2 comes before 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  presumably she visits all six cities and the only question is what order.  For every order that has Denver before San Francisco, the opposite order has San Francisco before Denver.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, however I'm not sure how to find every order that has Denver before San Francisco. How could I think about this?

Comment: My point is that you don't need to.  You have computed the total number of routes.  Half of them have Denver before San Francisco.  We can see that because we have a bijection between the two sets, so there are the same number of elements in each.   It is too many to reasonably list by hand.

Comment: Thank you, we haven't seen bijections so the only way we had to approach these questions so far is by finding the sample space of the situation and by finding the number of elements in the set of the event. That's why your explanation wasn't quite obvious to me.

Answer (score 2):

How convenient that this question was asked less than a week ago. I am currently working through old statistics problems because I am trying to prepare for the SOA - P exam, and this is the question I was *just* working on.

Nevertheless, here was my solution to the problem.

- *a*) It is apparent that order *will* matter here since if our cities are $A, B, C, D, E,$ and $F$, the itinerary $ABCDEF$ is different from itinerary $ABCDFE$. (*Think about it using a connect-the-dots analogy. The shape you make will be completely different if you don't connect the dots in the right order.*) Since order *does* matter, we will need to use a **permutation**. So, we have $6$ cities, and we're going to be permuting all $6$ of them. Thus there are $$N = P^6_6 = {6!\over(6-6)!} = {6!\over0!} = 6! = 720$$ possible itineraries. That is, the sample space, $S$, for possible itineraries has $720$ sample points
- *b*) We first need to determine the number of sample points in the sample space for the experiment $T$, the sample points in $S$ such that Denver, $D$, comes before San Francisco, $F$. Here, we're going to be **fixing** two cities to be constant. Hence, we will have $6$ cities, but permuting $4$ of them. In other words, $$N_T = P^6_4 = {6!\over(6-4)!} = {6!\over 2!}.$$ Thus, we use this result to give us $$P(\text{visit $D$ before $F$}) = {N_T\over N} = {6!\over 2!}\cdot{1\over 6!} = {1\over2!} = {1\over 2} = 0.5.$$

Comment: Is this saying that like Denver, San Fransisco, X1, X2, X3, X4. Then basically the question reduces to calculate the number of ways to arrange Xi?